# How does one create a new native token with full control?

Tags: native-assets

We would like to create a native asset on Cardano ourselves. How does one go about doing this?

Comment: You basically read the docs and if something is not clear, you may ask here https://developers.cardano.org/en/development-environments/native-tokens/native-tokens/
That being said, I don't think this is a valid question, since there are many resources about this topic out there.

Comment: @vaz This is the purpose of stackexchange. To create an easily searchable, consumable, and centralized body of knowledge on a topic. It is common to answer questions by linking to documentation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because No Research

Answer (score 3):

Here is a step-by-step recipe for creating a native asset manually: https://silas-stulz.medium.com/you-want-to-create-your-own-nft-heres-how-you-do-it-on-the-cardano-blockchain-9a0bbf8caa39.